# Embeddings of exotic spheres

Tags: differential-topology

Let $\{S^n_u \mid u\in \text{some indexing set} \}$ be the set of all non-diffeomorphic $n$-spheres. Define $k_u$ to be the smallest number such that there exists a smooth embedding $S^n_u\hookrightarrow \mathbb R^{k_u}$.

I am looking for the distribution of $k_u$ depending on the dimension $n$. Surely there are obvious bounds $$n+1\le \inf k_u \le \sup k_u \le 2n$$
but I'm looking for something more precise. (For trivial cases in which $n$-dimensional exotic spheres don't exist we simply have $k_u=n+1$, but I can't go any further).

Comment: For what its worth, my (extremely limited) understanding is if an exotic 4-sphere exists it can be embedded in R^5 (see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.5988.pdf).

Comment: Using embedding calculus you can argue $k_u \leq n+3$.  Presumably there are better estimates known -- I would look back to old papers of Haefliger and Hirsch on embeddings of highly-connected manifolds.

Comment: Thanks! You shed some light on it.

Comment: According to Moishe Kohan's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3222776/39599), if $\Sigma$ is an exotic sphere of dimension $n \geq 7$, then it cannot embed into $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. So, provided an exotic sphere exists in dimension $n \neq 4$, then $\sup k_u \geq n + 2$ (note that there no exotic spheres in dimensions $n = 5, 6$).

Comment: @RyanBudney I'm pretty sure that is not true, see e.g. Theorem 5.2 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.03109.pdf

Comment: @OscarRandal-Williams, thanks, that's a little unexpected (for me).   Apologies Pawel, I thought the bound $k_u \leq n+3$ was easily deduced.  Randal-Williams and Kupers have been thinking about this problem more carefully than I have.  The reason behind my mistake looks to be an important one.  I have been hoping to use embedding calculus to distinguish exotic spheres, although not in this way.  This gives me a little more hope than I already had.